# Hiding nth nested ULs after defined level

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<ul class="navTreeLevel0">
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <li></li>
        <ul class="navTreeLeve1">
          <li>
            <ul class="navTreeLevel2"></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any `li` could possibly have nth number of `li` that contain another `ul` level. Each `ul` level has an incrementing class `navTreeLevel(++)`. I am hiding the levels past 2 now with the following css.

```
.navTreeLevel3, navTreeLevel4 {
    display: none;
}
```

I don't control the html on the generation of this side bar. I want to be able to hide all levels after 2. (3,4,5,6,..) Is there a way to select the class by having all `.navTreeLevel` after 2?

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be easier to just hide all to start with and then show the ones you want.

```
ul[class^=navTreeLevel] {
    display:none;
}
.navTreeLevel0,.navTreeLevel1,.navTreeLevel2 {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Awesome approach to this problem. I like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just pick the last level to show, and add `ul` after it:

```
.navTreeLeve2 ul {
    display:none;
}
```

This hides all unordered lists below .navTreeLeve2.

Answer (score 0):

These answers helped me rethink my approach to this problem. I came up with the solution of hiding the third level because everything within that level will be hidden as well.

```
ul.navTreeLevel3{
    display: none;
}
```

With this nothing at level 3 or below will be visible.

Thank you for the answers.